# Create variables from existing variables to count them

Tags: php, variables, count

I have a project where a user can add people to a list, that includes name, male or female, and student or leader. Each person is either male or female and a student or leader.

I am trying to get the count for female students, female leaders, male students, and male leaders but not sure how to combine them to do the count. Something like:

```
$femaleStudent = $female && $student;
$maleStudent = $male && $student;
$femaleLeader = $female && $leader;
$maleLeader = $male && $leader;
```

Then do something like this:

```
$total = $femaleStudent + $maleStudent + $femaleLeader + $maleLeader;
```

How do I combine them so I can count them?

EDIT

$female, $male, $student, and $leader are just getting the count. Here is an example (this is in WordPress):

```
$female = array_count_values(array_column($participants, 'participant_gender'))['Female'];
```

The end result I am trying to show is the total number of people and then break it down by female student, female leader, male student, and male leader. My output is basically: Female Students: 8 Male Students = 6, Female Leaders = 2, Male Leaders = 2, Total = 18

EDIT 2

Here is an example of the participants array from a var_dump:

```
  0 => 
    array
      'participant_first_name' => string 'Steve'
      'participant_last_name' => string 'Rogers'
      'participant_gender' => string 'Male'
      'participant_age' => string '44'
      'participant_role' => string 'Leader'
  1 => 
    array
      'participant_first_name' => string 'Lois' 
      'participant_last_name' => string 'Lane' 
      'participant_gender' => string 'Female' 
      'participant_age' => string '15' 
      'participant_role' => string 'Student'
```

Comment: You had better show us with an example what is contained in these variables, it may help make sense of the question

Comment: An example of the required output may also help

Comment: **Show us in the question** thats where people look for info on the question use the "Edit" link under the question

Comment: There's no way to get the combined counts from the separate counts. You need to loop through the original data, performing both tests.

Comment: Can you show that participants array?

Comment: If `$female`  contains a number, and `$student` contains a number, how should these numbers (which don't have any more context) be combined by any logic?

Comment: I realize now that I need to loop through participants, I should have started with "here is my data" and then "here is what I'm trying to do".

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more of research and understanding what I did wrong, I was able to find a solution:

```
    $femaleStudent = 0;
    $maleStudent = 0;
    $femaleLeader = 0;
    $maleLeader = 0;

    foreach($participants as $participant => $v){
        $gender = $v['participant_gender'];
        $role = $v['participant_role'];
        
        if( $gender == "Male" && $role == "Student"){
            $maleStudent++;
        }
        if($gender == "Female" && $role == "Student") {
            $femaleStudent++;
        }
        if( $gender == "Male" && $role == "Leader"){
            $maleLeader++;
        }
        if($gender == "Female" && $role == "Leader") {
            $femaleLeader++;
        }
        
    }
    $total = count($participants);
```